# recover accidentaly closed opera window session from a file

Tags: linux, opera, browser-tabs

I've accidentaly lost my Opera session by moving a tab to a separate window, then closing main window with about 80 tabs opened first and new window second. I've managed to copy the `/home/user/.config/opera/Last Session` file to a safe location, and now I want to restore it. Unfortunately, when I copy it back to `/home/user/.config/opera/` and rename to `Current Session`, Opera starts with only speed dial opened, my copied session file becomes `Last Session` again and `Current Session` file get overridden with empty session anyway.

Is there a way to make Opera accept this file as a current session ? While I could extract website addresses from saved "Last Session" file, it seems tedious to manually reopen 80+ tabs while the session file is at hand (but for some reason it's not working)

I'm using Opera 44.0

Comment: Relevant: [Recover accidentally closed Opera window and its tabs after restarting](//superuser.com/q/136714)

Comment: @DavidPostill This question is 7 years old, most answers are outdated and target Windows, not Linux. The only ones that work for me involve manual reopening of URLs, which I want to avoid

Answer (score 1):

others have tried and failed to find a solution:
https://www.reddit.com/r/operabrowser/comments/61um2w/restore_last_accidentally_closed_session_in_opera/

It sounds like you are looking for a temporary solution to a problem that will probably continue to happen.

I suggest using the tedious method to restore your session and then taking one of the actions below to prevent having this type of issue in the future:

- Save tabs to folder on Speed Dial.
- Opera > Opera extension 'Download Chrome Extension' > Chrome extension 'Session Buddy'
- Use firefox and its session manager extension - http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/firefoxs-session-manager/